# Bottom view of Reminer app

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uikit

In bottom of default reminder app in iPhone, there are bar that can go directly to selected month......

What UiKit class can do this or is there any private framework?

Thank you for your answer....

Comment: I cant find such a bar in the reminder app. Can u please explain  a bit more?

Comment: @Jayashankar this one <http://tinypic.com/r/15vkf9/6>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a standard control available in UIKit. It's name is Page Control.

Here is a sample code : [Page Control demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)

Here is the class reference for page control : [UIPageControl class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)